# How to match a vector to a dataframe using mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame in which I'd like to make a new column which is set to `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether it matches with a vector.

So far I've tried two different approaches, the first directly using the `%in%` operator to check whether elements of `test` occurred in column `apples`, the second by putting this in an `ifelse` statement.

```
test <- c("a","b","c")
df <- tibble(apples = c("a","d","e","f","z","g","c"))

#First attempt
df_match <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    match = test %in% apples
  )

#Second attempt
df_match <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    match = ifelse(test %in% apples,TRUE,FALSE)
  )
```

The desired output for column 'match' would be

```
> df$match
[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: It's the other way round: `df %>% mutate(match = apples %in% test)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `base R`

```
 transform(df, match = apples %in% test)
```